# Си, рекуррентное вычисление

Tags: c, математика, рекурсия, ряды

Задано натуральное число n, действительное число x. Вычислить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя неудачная попытка:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    unsigned int n;
    float x;
    float y = 0;

    printf("Задайте числа n и x:\n");
    scanf("%u%f", &n, &x);

    int k;
    for (k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
    {
        y += (k / k + 1) - powf( cosf( fabsf(x)), k);
    }

    printf("%f\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Неудачная т.к. рекуррентное вычисление более оптимальное чем вычисления на каждой итерации (у меня получается только так). Как я могу переписать данный код, чтобы вычисления происходили рекуррентно?

Comment: 1. Нет рекуррентной природы в вашей задаче. 2. Рекуррентное вычисление всегда хуже, чем простой цикл.

Comment: Вам нужно обязательно рекуррентно - типа, препод зверь, требует..., или вы просто считаете, что рекуррентно - оно лучше?...

Comment: Требуют рекуррентно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала преобразуем ряд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, а потом уже будет ерундой его вычисление, особенно если вспомнить, что `cos` - функция четная :):

```
double s(double x, int n)
{
    double c = cos(x), z = 0;
    c = n - c*(pow(c,n)-1)/(c-1);
    for(int i = n; i >= 1; --i)
        z += 1./(i+1.);
    return c-z;
}
```

Обратите внимание на скобки в дроби в отличие от вашего `(k / k + 1)`, каковое всегда 2, да и на точки возле 1 (чтоб деление не было целочисленным).

Ага, пока писал, вы добавили необходимость рекуррентности. Ну что ж, тогда ряд считаем рекуррентно...

```
double fr(int k)
{
    if (k==1) return 1./2.;
    else return 1./(k+1.)+fr(k-1);
}

double s(double x, int n)
{
    double c = cos(x);
    c = n - c*(pow(c,n)-1)/(c-1);
    return c-fr(n);
}
```

Можно (по большому счету, нужно :)) отдельно обработать случай, когда `cos(x)==1`.

Еще один вариант...

```
double sum(int n, double x)
{
    double s = 0;
    double a = 0, b = 1, c = cos(x);
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
    {
        a += 1.0/k/(k+1);
        b *= c;
        s += a - b;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Ну, раз ставите минус - то не стесняйтесь, поясните, что у меня неверно?

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Однако и это решение мне не подошло по следующей причине: "Рекуррентное - это не рекурсивное. Чтобы реализовать последнее надо использовать функции. Для вычисления следующего элемента ряда достаточно знать предыдущий элемент."

Comment: Ну предложите еще один вариант (см. добавление в ответе)... Тут уж новый член вычисляется из старого...